# Wrong Eclipse "Correct Indentation" for Java varargs

Tags: java, eclipse

I rely on the Eclipse "Correct Indentation" (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) function but it does not indent correctly on varargs on multiple lines.

**Example**
**Original**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class WrongIndent
{
    String s = "Hello World";
    List x = Arrays.asList(
            s.substring(
                    1,
                    2)
            ,s.substring(
                    1,
                    2)
            ,s.substring(
                    2,
                    3)
            ,s.substring(
                    4,
                    5)
            );
}
```

**Output of "Correct Indentation"**

How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class WrongIndent
{
    String s = "Hello World";
    List x = Arrays.asList(
            s.substring(
                    1,
                    2)
                    ,s.substring(
                            1,
                            2)
                            ,s.substring(
                                    2,
                                    3)
                                    ,s.substring(
                                            4,
                                            5)
            );
}
```

Edit as requested: Eclipse Version Luna Release (4.4.0)

Comment: I can opt you for CTRL+SHIFT+F for formatting the code

Comment: What version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your formatter, tab "Line Wrapping" -> "Function Calls" -> "Arguments" and chose:

Line wrapping policy: Wrap all elements, every element on a new line
Force split: No
Indentation policy: Default Indentation

Comment: This works when I press CTRL+SHIFT+F (but that worked before I think) but not when I press CTRL+I.

Comment: :-/ I'm not aware of a way to change the indentation alone (i.e. there is no indentation preferences). You may have to fix this by selecting the lines you want to indent and Ctrl+Shift+F.